# HTC Incredible displaying blank ImageView

Tags: android, android-emulator, imageview, sd-card

I have an app that displays an an image in an ImageView using the setImageDrawable(Drawable) method.  However, with the release of the Droid Incredible the images are coming up as a blank screen.  I am using `Drawable.createFromPath(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "\\imagefile")` to access the image from the SD card.  I don't get any sort of error, just a black screen.  I will get a null pointer exception if after trying to load the image I try to access a property of the Drawable.  This makes me believe that the `Drawable` wasn't loaded, but I don't know why or how to make it work.

This code as been working on all other Android devices, so I'm not sure what is different with the Incredible.

Unfortunately I don't have access to an Incredible to test on, so I've got to rely on others to test and send me the log files.  Any help you can offer would be greatly appreciated.  If anyone knows how to replicate this issue on the emulator, that would be helpful too.  I've configured an emulator with firmware 7 and the correct screen resolution, but I was unable to replicate the issue.

Comment: "Unfortunately I don't have access to an Incredible to test on, so I've got to rely on others to test and send me the log files." -- if you are not doing so already, use Flurry or DroidDrop or something to send you the stack traces automatically. Also, bear in mind that not all Incredibles may have an SD card preinstalled, since they ship with a bunch of on-board flash. Verizon was supposed to ship an SD card, but review devices might not have one.

Answer (score 1):

The Incredible does not come with an SD card.  Instead, it has 8GB internal storage you can work with.  See [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/96f15e57150ed173/e325904dd01d8a9c?lnk=gst&q=incredible#) for more information.

Heh, I just noticed Mark already said this.

Comment: They are currently shipping with 2GB cards, actually. But that may be a limited-time promotional thing.

Comment: I think they are doing that now, but it didn't start like that.  There are probably a lot of phones out there now without an SD card

Answer (score 0):

I've verified that it's not an issue with the SD card (although that is another issue to be addressed).  Using an Incredible with an SD card installed produces the result described above as does saving/loading the image from the internal memory ("/emmc").